# Remove and add class with body_class() function

Tags: post-class, body-class

I want to remove the default body class on the theme and add a new class.

I use this code to do this:

```
//REMOVE / ADD HOME CLASS FROM BODY

add_filter('body_class', function (array $classes) {
    if (in_array('home', $classes)) {
      unset( $classes[array_search('home', $classes)] );
    }
  return $classes;
});

add_filter('body_class', function (array $classes) {
    if (in_array('blog', $classes)) {
      unset( $classes[array_search('blog', $classes)] );
    }
  return $classes;
});



add_action( 'body_class', 'my_custom_class');
function my_custom_class( $classes ) {
  $classes[] = 'my-custom-class';
  return $classes;
}
```

The code works because the two default classes disappear and the new class appears, but when I create "my_custom_class" in `style.css`, the CSS doesn't work.

I tried to modify the margin for example, I use this code:

```
.my_custom_class {
    margin-top: 350px !important;
}
```

but on site there are no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `my_custom_class()` function is using the class name `my-custom-class`, but the CSS is targeting the class `my_custom_class`. These two strings should be exactly the same:

```
.my-custom-class {
    margin-top: 350px !important;
}
```

Also, it would be a little cleaner to handle all of the `body_class` stuff in a single callback function:

```
add_action( 'body_class', 'my_custom_class');
function my_custom_class( $classes ) {
    // Remove 'blog' class
    if (in_array('blog', $classes)) {
        unset( $classes[array_search('blog', $classes)] );
    }

    // Remove 'home' class
    if (in_array('home', $classes)) {
        unset( $classes[array_search('home', $classes)] );
    }

    // Add custom class
    $classes[] = 'my-custom-class';

    return $classes;
}
```